# Optimize CellForRow Method for multiple cells

Tags: ios, optimization

Can anyone help me with how to optimize following code if we do have same contents inside both the cells such like 2 labels and 1 imageview than.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView == booksTbl) { // Your conditions here to choose between Books and Movies
    BookCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bookCell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:@"bookCell"];
    }
    return cell;
} else {
    MovieCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"movieCell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:@"movieCell"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I have tried by taking UITablewViewCell As common and according to condition, i was casting it with the appropriate cell. But it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
BookCell *cell = (BookCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bookCell"];


if(cell == nil){
    // NSLog(@"---Cell Allocated Memory---");
    cell = (BookCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BookCell" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    [cell setRestorationIdentifier:@"bookCell"];
}
```